# How to update file in git so that GitHub PR won't show it changed?

Tags: git, github, diff, pull-request, git-diff

I have a PR in GitHub. There was some line-ending issue, merges, but now the file in both branches `A` and `B` is the same, but GitHub shows it as changed. ***This is not a line ending issue.*** `git ls-files --eol` and `git diff A..B` indicate that the files are actually the same. Plus, I "save as" the files from GitHub by clicking `[Raw]`, and see that line endings are the same.

Is there a way to fix this apart from re-creating a branch and/or pull request?

Comment: Maybe check also the potential `fileMode` issue (the execution bit might be different for different filesystems)

Answer (score 0):

Please try reverting that file to upstream commit by using git history for that file and push that change.